# I need to get a new "image tag" with IF functions

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add an image only if the item is new.

I'm using a .json file.

To know if a item is new I'm using:

```
<?php
$daytoday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));
$dateOfItem = $item['itemDate'];
?>
```

And I've tried this:

```
<?php if ($daytoday == $dateOfItem): ?>
    <div class="main-shop">
        <img width="30" height="15" src="newitemtag" class="newitem">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="<?php echo $item['fullimage']; ?>">
        <div class="nametitle">
            <?php echo $item['name']; ?><br>
        </div>
        <div class="priceposition">
            <div class="price">
                <?php echo $item['price']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="main-shop">
        <img width="150" height="150" src="<?php echo $item['fullimage']; ?>">
        <div class="nametitle">
            <?php echo $item['name']; ?><br>
        </div>
        <div class="priceposition">
            <div class="price">
                <?php echo $item['price']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Whats `src="newitemtag"`?

Comment: Post the json so we can see the item's date format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the if statement was wrapped around just the "new" image the code would be more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), which is one of the SOLID principles of good code. That way if something has to change it only needs to be changed once.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your `$daytoday` and `$dateOfItem` values are not the same.

The following will give you the timestamp for midnight on the current day and then format it like `2019-09-22`:

```
$daytoday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today'));
```

It's not clear what value is here:

```
$dateOfItem = $item['itemDate'];
```

But my guess is it's different somehow. Look closely at the format you're receiving it in. You could also try `echo`-ing it out just before the `if` or using a debugger to see what the values are when the `if` expression is evaluated.

If it turns out to be a unix timestamp, you might be better off with something like:

```
$daytoday = strtotime('today');
if ($dateOfItem >= $daytoday):
```

This will also catch any item dates that are set to a time that is even more recent than midnight of the current day.

PS: For consistency and readability, your variable name `$daytoday` should be `$dayToday` (note the capital T). Also, Jason Aller's comment about surrounding only the varying part of your HTML with the `if` statement in order to be more DRY is excellent advice.